# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR from CLOB

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to find a substring from a CLOB-field in my database.

Consider the following string:

> someothertext 2. Grad Dekubitus (Druckgeschwür) mit
> Abschürfung/Blase/Hautverlust someothertext

I only want to extract the **"2. Grad"** from the string, but my Regexp doesn't seem to work - I tested it on the string in some online regexp checkers, where it does actually work ([Fiddle](http://regexr.com/5rbi2))

This is my regular expression:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(cf.TEXT, 4000), '\b[0-9]\.\sGrad$') AS "Grad"
```

Currently, it returns NULL, but I'm not sure why.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Try it without the anchor `$`

Comment: Oracel regex does not support word boundaries. `[0-9]\.\sGrad` will work. Or, ``(^|\D)([0-9]\.\sGrad)``, if you need to make sure there is no digit before the `[0-9]`.

Comment: According [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303) `REGEXP_SUBSTR` works also with `CLOB`, i.e. you don't have to convert into `VARCHAR2`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit for me it doesn't work, if I don't convert it I get the following error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Comment: Ok, never mind. Maybe a documentation bug. Or you have an old Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle regex does not support word boundaries. Also, the `$` is redundant in your pattern (note you do not use it in your regex demo).

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    'someothertext 2. Grad Dekubitus (Druckgeschwür) mit Abschürfung/Blase/Hautverlust someothertext', 
    '(^|\D)([0-9]\.\sGrad)', 1, 1, NULL, 2
) AS "Grad"
```

where

- `(^|\D)` - Group 1: start of string or a non-digit
- `([0-9]\.\sGrad)` - Group 2: a digit, a dot, as whitespace and `Grad`

If the digit matched with `[0-9]` should be preceded with whitespace, you may replace `(^|\D)` with `(\s|^)`.

Comment: Hello Wiktor, I didn't know that the Oracle Regex doesn't support this, thanks for your quick help, it's working now :).

Comment: @Max Word boundaries are treacherous as their meaning is context-dependent. I suggest here a digit and a whitespace boundary, please choose the one that works best for you.

Comment: @Max `1, 1, NULL, 2` stand for *start looking for a match beginning with the first char in the string* (`1`), *return the first match* (`1`), *without passing additional flags* (`NULL`), and *the string returned must be Group 2 value* (`2`).

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not support word boundaries `\b` in regular expressions.

Either remove the `\b` or replace it with `(^|\s)` if you are expecting white space before the digit.

You also need to remove the trailing `$` as you are not trying to match the end of the string at that point.

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(cf.TEXT, 4000), '(^|\s)[0-9]\.\sGrad' ) AS "Grad"
```

Also, if you can have multi-digit numbers then you may want to use `[0-9]+`.

If you do not want the leading white space then you can wrap the second part of your expression in a capturing group and then extract that capturing group's value with the 6th argument of `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(
  DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(cf.TEXT, 4000),
  '(^|\s)([0-9]\.\sGrad)',
  1,    -- Start from the 1st character
  1,    -- Find the 1st occurrence
  NULL, -- No flags
  2     -- Return the 2nd capturing group
) AS "Grad"
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the capturing groups, I'm not yet an expert in Regular Expressions, that helps quite well! And also thanks for your great explanation :).